# Verbose-trad2: Getting "cit." instead of "op.cit"

Tags: biblatex

as stated in the title, for repeating citations I am getting:

```
Shedroff, Design is the problem: the future of design must be sustainable, cit., pp. xxxiv–xxxv.
```

Instead, I would like to have

```
Shedroff, Design is the problem: the future of design must be sustainable, op. cit., pp. xxxiv–xxxv.
```

My setup for bibliography is:

```
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            backend=biber,  
            ibidpage=true,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=none,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
        ]{biblatex} 
        
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}}


\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\textit{\autocap{i}d}},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\textit{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {\mkbibemph{\textit{\autocap{i}vi}}},
}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}
```

Comment: To clarify: Is the only change that you want to see to have "op. cit." display as "cit." or is there some else going on (e.g. you need both "op. cit." and "cit." in the same document with different meanings)?

Comment: For future questions, please note that it is *much* more useful to provide a complete example document (starting with `\documentclass` and including a short `\begin{document}...\end{document}` body with just enough contents to reproduce the situation you are asking about). If you only show us certain parts of your preamble, we have to waste time turning it into a compilable example to test out solutions and in certain situations we may have to guess the completion (which may well turn out to be at odds with how you actually do things).

Comment: Hi @moewe thank you for the reply. Sorry, I thought including the setup for bibliography was enough! To clarify, yes I would like to see "op.cit", instead of just "cit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `italian.lbx` the bibstring `opcit` is translated as "cit.". If you want "op. cit.", try something like

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\textit{\autocap{i}d}},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\textit{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {\mkbibemph{\textit{\autocap{i}vi}}},
  opcit          = {op\adddotspace cit\adddot},
}
```